# Updating tkinter labels

Tags: python, tkinter

Why won't the variable `AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable` update? I have tried `mainloop`, `configure`, and `set` but it stays the same. I want it to choose a random question out of the list `TrueQuestions` every time the `MainMenuButton1Command` (start button) is pressed.

```
#imports
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import *
import random
#lists
TrueQuestions = [
    'true question 1',
    'true question 2',
    'true question 3',]
current_question = random.choice(TrueQuestions)
#command defines
def MainMenuButton1Command():
    MainMenu.withdraw()
    AnswerQuestionPage.deiconify()
    #attempting to update AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable when start button pressed
    current_question = random.choice(TrueQuestions)
    AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable.set(current_question)
def MainMenuButton5Command():
    quit()
def AnswerQuestionPageButton1Command():
    AnswerQuestionPage.withdraw()
    MainMenu.deiconify()
#MainMenu
MainMenu = Tk()
MainMenu.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
MainMenu.title("IQ extreme Main Menu")
MainMenu.configure(bg="blue")
BigFont = Font(family="Tahoma",size=48,weight="bold")
SmallFont = Font(family="Tahoma",size=24)
TinyFont = Font(family="Tahoma",size=18)
MainMenuButton1 = Button(MainMenu,bg="white",fg="black",font=TinyFont,text="Start",width=20,command=MainMenuButton1Command)
MainMenuButton1.place(x=525,y=400)
MainMenuButton5 = Button(MainMenu,bg="red",fg="black",font=TinyFont,text="Quit",width=5,command=MainMenuButton5Command)
MainMenuButton5.place(x=1200,y=950)
#AnswerQuestionPage
AnswerQuestionPage = Tk()
AnswerQuestionPage.withdraw()
BigFont = Font(AnswerQuestionPage,family="Tahoma",size=48,weight="bold")
SmallFont = Font(AnswerQuestionPage,family="Tahoma",size=24)
TinyFont = Font(AnswerQuestionPage,family="Tahoma",size=18)
AnswerQuestionPage.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
AnswerQuestionPage.title("IQ extreme")
AnswerQuestionPage.configure(bg="blue")
AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable = StringVar()
AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable.set(current_question)
AnswerQuestionPageText2 = Label(AnswerQuestionPage,bg="blue",fg="black",font=BigFont,text="Question: "+str(current_question))
AnswerQuestionPageText2.place(x=350,y=50)
AnswerQuestionPageButton1 = Button(AnswerQuestionPage,bg="white",fg="black",font=TinyFont,text="Home",width=5,command=AnswerQuestionPageButton1Command)
AnswerQuestionPageButton1.place(x=1205,y=5)
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please remove anything not relevant to the problem? You seem to have neither random selection logic nor setting that to your StringVar in `MainMenuButton1Command`, so I'm not surprised nothing gets updated.

Comment: @Reti43 Got rid of unnecessary code and also edited in my attempts to get ```AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable``` to update. Hopefully, that helps.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  A minimal reproducible example should be much shorted than what I see now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can see working code for textvariable:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import *
import random
# lists
TrueQuestions = [
    'true question 1',
    'true question 2',
    'true question 3', ]
current_question = random.choice(TrueQuestions)
AnswerQuestionPage = Tk()
BigFont = Font(AnswerQuestionPage, family="Tahoma", size=48, weight="bold")
SmallFont = Font(AnswerQuestionPage, family="Tahoma", size=24)
TinyFont = Font(AnswerQuestionPage, family="Tahoma", size=18)
AnswerQuestionPage.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
AnswerQuestionPage.title("IQ extreme")
AnswerQuestionPage.configure(bg="blue")
AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable = StringVar()
AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable.set(current_question)
AnswerQuestionPageText2 = Label(AnswerQuestionPage,
                                bg="blue",
                                fg="black",
                                font=BigFont,
                                textvariable=AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable)
AnswerQuestionPageText2.place(x=350, y=50)
AnswerQuestionPage.mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you added a description of what you did differently. Otherwise, we have to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character.

Answer (score 2):

You must say to `AnswerQuestionPageText2` Label to use `AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable` with: `Label(textvariable=AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable, ...)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this makes ```AnswerQuestionPageText2``` not appear at all, whereas before it would appear but just not update. Unless I am doing something wrong... ```AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable = StringVar()
AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable.set(current_question)
AnswerQuestionPageText2 = Label(AnswerQuestionPage,bg="blue",fg="black",font=BigFont,textvariable=AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable)```

Comment: You must set the variable to any value with .set()

Comment: but you can see with the code in my previous comment I did add the line ```AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable.set(current_question)```

Comment: But you did not add the textvariable=AnswerQuestionPageText2Variable to the Label.

Comment: There are other problems in you code beyond textvariable. You must not call Tk() twice for example.